# Fix material with no texture?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made a new diffused material for grass in unity5 when applied it to a somrthing small in size it has all the details of the texture grass image but when applied the same material to a much larger objects only solid color is visible with no details of the texture.

refer the down given image.
[image]

both the cube and the floor has same material.

**MaterialSetting**

[image]

Comment: Can you post you material setup screenshoot? Tiling setting problem?

Comment: My guess is that your texture is set to clamped instead of repeat.

Comment: Updated @maximelian1986. Where can i find clamped & repeat setting?

Comment: First try to increase tiling like 100*100 (dont remember how it is working). but clamped & repeat you can find in texture import settings.

Comment: it is already in repeat !!

Comment: could you try scaling up the cube and see what happens ? if the texture starts to stretch or repeat ?

Answer (score 0):

Increase the tiling. The image will stretch to be 1 x 1 on a huge object the way you have it in your image. The higher the tile count the more the image will be repeated across the object.

Be aware the x and y values may be different to one another depending on the dimensions of the gameobject it is attached to.

Comment: Increased the tiling value but again the effect was only visible on the cube and the cliff remain of solid color

Comment: Can I ask some questions then. Is this a custom mesh you have imported into unity? Is it a terrain? Can you give the x,y,z scale values?

Comment: It is a cliff prefab that i got it from asset store, the scale values are 5,5,5

Comment: It sounds like an issue with the model itself, likely there is a problem with it's UV map. Try applying other custom textures to the model to see if you get the same result.